# jQuery sortable - Need to add GUID as id of the DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to add GUID as id of the li DOM element like below:

```
<ul>
  <li id="item-{78C9267C-1A41-BCCD-392D-06DA2C4198B1}"></li>
</ul>
```

so that I can serialize this using jquery sortable. Currently following code is resulting in JSON.parse invalid character error:

```
$("ul").sortable({
  update:function() {
    var sorted = $(this).sortable( "serialize" );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.sortable( "serialize" , { expression : /(.+)-{(.+)}/ })`

Answer (score 1):

[`serialize`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) will not build a valid JSON:

> Serializes the sortable's item ids into a form/ajax submittable
>   string. Calling this method produces a hash that can be appended to
>   any url to easily submit a new item order back to the server.

To build up a valid JSON starting from your sorted elements you can use [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) your sortable elements get as string array using [`toArray`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray), code:

```
$("ul").sortable({
    update: function () {
        var sorted = JSON.stringify($(this).sortable('toArray'));
        console.log(sorted)
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Qwx2U/